# Why `break label` cannot be used inside lambda expression? Any workaround?

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, httpclient, netty

I am trying to implement a retry mechanism for HTTP request with a HTTPClient library. For the retry mechanism, I have a list of website to try and I will try each website for `retries` times. The process ends when I receive a `status 200` from any of the requests.

My idea is to use a boolean `requestSuccess` and a label `requestLabel`. I will set `requestSuccess = true` and break the `requestLabel` when I receive a `status 200`. However, variable must be `(effectively) final` and `break` label is not available inside lambda expression.

**Is there any workaround to implement such retry mechanism?**

```
boolean requestSuccess = false;

requestLabel: 
for(String site: sites) {
    for(int i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
        client.request(site, data, requestOptions, (err, res, content) -> {
            if(err == null) {
                requestSuccess = true;
                break requestLabel;
            } else {
                log(...);
            }
        })
    }
}

if(!requestSuccess) {
    log("request failed");
}
```

**One possible answer**

Inspired by a submitted then deleted answer, I can use a wrapped-class-like solution. I think it would work, but it seems dirty?

```
boolean[] requestSuccess = new boolean[1];

requestLabel:
for(String site: sites) {
    for(int i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
        if(requestSuccess[0] == true) {
            break requestLabel;
        }

        client.request(site, data, requestOptions, (err, res, content) -> {
            if(err == null) {
                requestSuccess[0] = true;
            } else {
                log(...);
            }
        })
    }
}

if(!requestSuccess) {
    log("request failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda gets turned into it's own class under the hood. It would be as if you have two classes as far as the java interpreter is concerned.

```
class Main {
    public void runstuff() {
        labelX:
        for(...) {
            client.request(new Main$Foo().xyz(.....));
        }
    }

    class Foo {
         public xyz(....) {
             break labelX; // There is no labelX to break to here in Foo.xyz
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andyk. If I get this correctly, if a request matches on one of the sites, you want that site to handle it, correct? In your current setup you're doing a good luck approach and wasting many resources. If you have 20 sites that don't match, you have have 20 404's if you're lucky. I'd suggest you'd filter out the sites first. Then try the request on the proper site. Which http library are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code is for a reverses proxy, which accepts a request and re-direct to another location. So I do expect the request to work most of the time, but when it does not, I have to retry. I thought of a potential answer. Can you have a look please(updated in the question)?

Comment: The compiler does not complain. Since arr is an array object, the value of `arr`(the reference) won't  change when I do `arr[0]  = true` inside the lambda.

Comment: Hmm, true, as long as the array won't change that will work.